# Firebird checking types within columns

Tags: python, firebird

I'd like to run something along the lines of the pseudo code in the cur.execute('stuff') line:

```py
import fdb

tableName = "MostCertainlyNotHelloWorldTable"

con = fdb.connect(dsn="dsnString",user="MostCertainlyNotSYSDBA",password="MostCertainlyNotMasterkey")
cur = con.cursor()

# this is my pseudo-code
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE Type(column) IS NOT BLOB") 
# The idea is to remove all BLOB type columns within a given table from the SELECT command's output for that table

for row in cur.fetchall():
    for col in row:
        print(col, end = ',')
    print()
```

I need to print all columns inside a given table from a firebird database, EXCEPT (as mentioned in the code comment) those that have "BLOB" as their input type. To be fair I'm not going to print stuff, I'm actually going to append them into a text file, but I guess printing yields the same result (I think?) without flooding project folders.

I'd like something that allows me to filter data by type - namely, excluding BLOBs - but still allows me to get a csv-like format (columns within a row separated by single commas, rows separated by '\n').

If it's NOT POSSIBLE to filter BLOB's out, I need a way to deal with BLOB columns that have commas inside their values, as those effectively break my tables' structure.

So I need either:

- A way to completely skip BLOB columns.

or

- A way to deal with the commas inside them.

Comment: You can't do that in the query itself. Either you must inspect the metadata tables and construct an appropriate query including only the relevant columns, or you need to do a type introspection on the cursor and skip columns with a blob. However, your actual problem sounds like you need to use an appropriate library to write out CSV that escapes/quotes values properly (eg the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/csv.html))

Comment: @MarkRotteveel one more problem is if (maybe not) he has binary BLOBs as opposite to text BLOBs. Then he has to convert them to one or another text representation, before they can be presented to user in CSV or screen form. Be it mere hex bytes dump, or UUE/base64/yEnc encoders. However even in transformed from they would be suitable for another computer program, reading CSV/JSON/XML/whatever. But a human operator, if human is the end target, would typically not be able to parse binary dumps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented earlier, you cannot do this in the query itself. Either you must inspect the metadata tables and construct an appropriate query including only the relevant columns, or you need to do a type introspection on the cursor and skip columns with a blob.

For example, to skip blob columns in FDB, you can do something like:

```
import fdb
import csv

def is_blob(descriptor):
    return (descriptor[fdb.DESCRIPTION_DISPLAY_SIZE] == 0 
        and descriptor[fdb.DESCRIPTION_INTERNAL_SIZE] == 8)

with fdb.connect(dsn="localhost:exampledb", user="sysdba", password="masterkey") as con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM DATAEXAMPLE") 

    with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        for row in cur.fetchall():
            values = [column for index, column in enumerate(row) 
                        if not is_blob(cur.description[index])]
            writer.writerow(values)
```

The check for display size 0 and internal size 8 will identify blobs. This is a bit of a kludge, but the type_code (`fdb.DESCRIPTION_TYPE_CODE`) in `Cursor.description` does not provide sufficient information to discern blobs from non-blobs.

I'm also using the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/csv.html) to generate to CSV file. This will fix problems with for example varchar columns containing commas in their value by quoting values. Check the documentation of `csv` if you need to fine tune the CSV file generated. The default generates CSV that is compatible with how Microsoft Excel reads and writes CSV.

Using the CSV module could allow you to include blob columns (assuming they are `blob sub_type text`) as well. This might depend on whether or not the consumer can live with newlines inside a value or not. If you also have `blob sub_type binary` columns, you may need to do something extra for those, like base64 encoding the value before including it in the CSV.